# Make array with reverse order numbers

Tags: c++

I am to make 3 arrays, one of randnumbers, one in order, and one in reverse order. My reverse order array won't work. Size, randOrderArr, inOrderArr, and revOrderArr are all in my SortingClass class. Here is my code, how do i fix it to make the revOrderArr be the array with reverse numbers?

```
SortingClass::SortingClass(int si, int sm, int la){
size=si;
randArr = new int[si];
inOrderArr = new int[si];
revOrderArr = new int[si];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i<si; i++){
    //srand(time(NULL));
    int randnum = rand()%(la-sm+1)+sm;
    randArr[i]=randnum;
    inOrderArr[i]=(sm+i);
    revOrderArr[i]=(la-1-i);
}
```

}

Comment: Are 3 arrays unrelated or should they have some dependencies ? (as inOrderArr should be the randArr sorted in increase order, and `revOrderArr` is `inOrderArr` in reverse order).

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should not be in the loop, call it only once. and now there are facility from `<random>` which are better than `rand()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what `la` is.  Why not just use `sm` to figure out `revOrderArr` also?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `(la-i)`?

Comment: "la" is the largest number, when i put just "(la-i)" it still just prints out: 1,2,3,4,5,6,.....

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create an array of random numbers and two other arrays that represent the sorted (ascending and descending) versions of the arrays, using C++11, you can do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

void fillRandomArrays(
  int arraySize,
  int minValue,
  int maxValue,
  std::vector<int>& unsorted,
  std::vector<int>& sortedAscending,
  std::vector<int>& unsortedDescending
) {
  std::random_device randomDevice;
  std::mt19937 mersenneTwister(randomDevice);

  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minValue, maxValue);

  //fill the random unsorted array
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(unsorted), arraySize, [&]() {
    return distribution(mersenneTwister);
  });

  //fill the sorted ascending array
  std::copy(std::begin(unsorted), std::end(unsorted), std::back_inserter(sortedAscending));
  std::sort(std::begin(sortedAscending), std::end(sortedAscending), std::less<int>());

   //fill the sorted descending array
  std::copy(sortedAscending.rbegin(), sortedAscending.rend(), std::back_inserter(sortedDescending));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but I don't appreciate the sarcasm. I wish you would have worded that differently.

Comment: I acknowledge that my comment was snarky.  I have deleted it, and I apologize.  However, the point was that this neither answers the OP's question, nor brings them any closer to understanding why their posted code doesn't work correctly.  This is almost certainly a homework assignment (I can't think of a good reason to do what OP is asking for otherwise), so its purpose is to help the OP learn something.  Spoon-feeding them a complete program (which probably uses concepts they haven't even learned yet) does not help them to learn whatever it is that the assignment was meant to teach them.

Comment: Point taken. I should use more discretion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong populating equation for the `revOrderArr`.

Use `revOrderArr[i]=(la-i);` instead.